# Absolute value for floats in core OCaml

Tags: floating-point, ocaml, absolute-value

I am in need of an absolute value function for floats in OCaml and the core language doesn't seem to possess one, so I wrote the following:

```
let absF (f:float) = if f > 0.0 then f else (f *. -1.0);;
```

which seems to work for positives but not for negatives, citing:

This expression has type float -> float but is here used with type int

What is the error in my logic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you type

```
absF -1.0;;
```

OCaml interprets it as

```
(absF) - (1.0);;
```

i.e. as a subtraction.  Instead, do

```
absF (-1.0);;
```

Answer (score 15):

The core language does have one, `abs_float`.

Also, you can use `~-.` to denote unary negation, and this applies to integers as well with the `~-` operator. You can define such an operator (even though it already exists) like this:

```
let (~-) a : int = 0 - a
let (~-.) a : float = 0.0 -. a
```

Answer (score 5):

if you have int value can use

```
# abs(-1)
- : int = 1
```

else if you have a float

```
# abs_float(-1.0)
- : float = 1.
```